# Using -replace on pipes in powershell

Tags: powershell, find-and-replace, pipe, cat

I want to test out a replace before I use it, so I'm trying to write a quick online command to see what the output is. However, I'm not sure what the syntax is. What I want to do is something like

```
cat file | -replace "a", "b"
```

What is the correct powershell syntax for this?

I know that I can also do `$a = cat file` and then do a replace on `$a`, but I'de like to keep this on one line

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should do the trick, it'll go through all the lines in the file, and replace any "a" with "b", but you'll need to save that back into a file afterwards

```
cat file | foreach {$_.replace("a","b")} | out-file newfile
```

Comment: Any way to treat the whole file as one string instead of multiples? I.e. to replace line-endings?

Comment: `cat`, which is just an alias for `Get-Content` ingest the whole file, and this just goes through each line and do a replace on it. To replace line-ending, do you only care about the last line-ending? or each new paragraphs?

Comment: Why do you think, you need to write it to a file?

Comment: I guess you don't for what the OP wanted. But if you do want to "save" the changes, one way is to write it back to a file.

Answer (score 16):

To use the [Powershell -replace operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) (which works with regular expressions) do this:

```
cat file.txt | foreach {$_ -replace "\W", ""} # -replace operator uses regex
```

note that the -replace operator uses regex matching, whereas the following example would use a non-regex text find and replace, as it uses the [String.Replace method of the .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
cat file | foreach {$_.replace("abc","def")} # string.Replace uses text matching
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add the possibility to use the above mentioned solution **as input for command pipes** which require **slashes instead of backslashes**.

I hit this while using [jest](https://jestjs.io/) under Windows, whereby jest requires slashes and Windows path autocompletion returns backslashes:

```
.\jest.cmd .\path\to\test  <== Error; jest requires "/"
```

Instead I use:

```
.\jest.cmd (echo .\path\to\test | %{$_ -replace "\\", "/"})
```

which results to

```
.\jest.cmd ./path/to/test
```

---

Even **multiple paths** could be "transformed" by using an array `(echo path1, path2, path3 | ...)`. For example to specify also a config file I use:

```
.\jest.cmd --config (echo .\path\to\config, .\path\to\test | %{$_.replace("\", "/")})

.\jest.cmd --config ./path/to/config ./path/to/test
```

The nice thing is that you still could use the native path autocompletion to navigate to your files.

Comment: You also may use an regexp: `%{$_ -replace("\\", "/")}`.

Comment: off-topic and adds no new information